# How can I verify my machine is not vulnerable from a specific exploit?

Tags: linux, exploit

I'm running Ubuntu 8.04 TLS linux 2.6.24-23, I find that CVE-2009-2692 which exploits by using sock_sendpage() null pointer dereference. It describes this exploit affects linux version prior to 2.6.31 and I find patched version of Ubuntu 8.04 is linux 2.6.24-24. I attempted to run this exploit on my machine, but I couldn't make it work due to mmap permission denied. Does that mean kernel 2.6.24-23 is not vulnerable from this exploit?

Comment: If you have follow the exploit guide and you have execute it and it has not exploited your machine you can be pretty sure your machine is not vulnerable to that CVE.

Comment: @kiBytes That's not entirely accurate. Not every exploit attempt is guaranteed to lead to a successful exploitation of a vulnerability.

Comment: 8.04 LTS? Isn't that a dinosaur system now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No - it does not mean you are not vulnerable.

The patches you have installed may have fixed the particular vulnerability, but failure of a test does not automatically mean you are safe - it could just be the case that your test version is misconfigured, failed due to a local configuration or bug, or has had some other problem.

The usual way to gain assurance is to look at the CVE description and patching recommendations and cross reference with your own patching/versions.

If in doubt, use a professional penetration tester.